# Any ole db provider/consumer for PostgreSQL?

Tags: c++, postgresql, oledb

I'm working with c++ visual studio 2015, currently i'm using sql server for database but now i'm switching on postgres DB but i'm not getting any relevent OLE DB consumer/provider please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can either work with [PGNP OLEDB Provider for PostgreSQL, Greenplum and Redshift](http://www.pgoledb.com) or use a combination of [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc) and [psqlODBC](https://odbc.postgresql.org).

Although the second combination involves more components (and, probably, more layers), it's probably more up-to-date.