# Migrating a C# application to connect to PostGres database

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, database-migration

I have inherited the maintenance of a C#  (Windows 10, dot net 2.0) database application that uses OleDb to connect to databases.

OleDb has been used because it has allowed previous versions of the application to switch between databases (MS Access, SQL Server, Oracle etc) simply by changing the connection string.

The application is now due to be moved to a PostGres database. I have successfully managed to connect to the database using either Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection or  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection (using  the Intillisoft postgres data provider found here… http://www.pgoledb.com )

The OleDb provider requires a prohibitively large fee (the application is hosted by a charity, I’m doing the work on a voluntary basis) . So I’m going to have to use the Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection class, but there are several hundred occurrences of OleDbConnection objects being passed around in the application.

My objectives are (in order of importance)

1. Migrate the application to PostGre
2. Make the minimum of changes to the code
3. Maintain the ability to switch between data sources (if possible)

I'd like some advice please on the best approach to achieving these objectives. I'm hoping there's some way to create my own class called OleDbConnection which would link to either System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection OR Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection depending on parameters. This would maintain data-source flexibility and keep code changes to a minimum - but I've no idea if this is even possible, let alone how to do it!

Thanks

Comment: Though it would require you to change some pieces of code, (not to much if the application is designed well) but entity framework might be a nice thing to look into.

Comment: "not to much if the application is designed well" - "but there are several hundred occurrences of OleDbConnection objects being passed around" - So I wouldn't bet a dime on it, @MarkBaijens

Comment: Yeah doesn't sound like a very well design. Still refactoring tools can help with some of that.

Comment: You can consider ODBC, which allows changing provider easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any ole db provider/consumer for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819342/any-ole-db-provider-consumer-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

Switching DB vendors becomes a lot simpler when you program to interfaces. Passing around instances of specific connection type is something that you need to fix before migrating the core logic of your program to a different RDBMS.

A common interface for DB connections is IDbConnection: both OleDbConnection and NpgsqlConnection implement it. Go through your source tree, replace all occurrences of OleDbConnection with IDbConnection, and recompile the project. You may need to convert other types to interfaces, e.g. OleDbCommand to IDbCommand.

If this step is successful (it should be) the remaining migration would be a lot simpler. If errors turn up on recompiling, you would need to ask specific questions about converting code specific to OleDB.